# Why this sharedpreferences not working in flutter?

Tags: flutter

**trying to get saved  data by sharedpreferences**
while I am practicing flutter sharedpreferences is not saving anything(posting my code below)

- firstly created one textfield, button and one textwidget to show what I typed in textfield when I click button
- I think everything ok there is not showing any error but when I click button text widget will show what I typed but that not saving to get after the app closed(code below)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String text = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStringValuesSF();
  }

  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      text = _controller.text;
                    });
                    SharedPreferences prefs =
                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    prefs.setString('stringValue', text);
                  },
                  child: Text("Show bigger")),
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//method to get the string
  getStringValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    String stringValue = prefs.getString('stringValue');
    this.text = stringValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the value to the String "text" not the "_controller.text"...

Answer (score 1):

you just have to change below method,

```
  getStringValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    String stringValue = prefs.getString('stringValue');
   _controller.text  = stringValue;   //change !!!
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use setState to see changes after fetching data:-

```
getStringValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    String stringValue = prefs.getString('stringValue');
    setState((){this.text = stringValue;});
  }
```